# phonegap android login form

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, phonegap-plugins

****why i m failed to get validations at mobile end i m not getting validations on fields even getting applied validation in browser but failed to get in mobile .can anyone point me what am i doing wrong?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>first example</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jqm.page.params.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/lib/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/additional-methods.min.js">
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lib/helloworldjs/alldatabse.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(
 function()
  { $("#formregistration").validate(
    { rules:{
          usernameforreg:
             {
              required:true,
              minlength:4,
              maxlength:10

             },
          useremail:
             {
              required:true,
              email:true

             },
         passwordforreg:
              {
              required:true,
              minlength:8
              },
         retypepassword:
             {
             required:true,
             equalTo:"#passwordforreg"
             }
            },
      messages:{
          usernameforreg:
             {
              required:"pls enter name",
             minlength:$.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
             maxlength:$.format("Maximum {0} characters allowed!")

             },
         useremail:
             {
             required:"pls enter email id",
             email:"enter valid email id"
             },
        passwordforreg:
              {
              required:"pls enter password",
              minlength:$.format("at least {0} characters required!")
              },     
         retypepassword:
             {
             required:"pls confirm password",
             equalTo:"both passwords must match"
             }

             }

    });
     $("#formlogin").validate(
       {rules:
           {username:
                {
                  required:true,
                  minlength:4
                },
             password:
               {
                 required:true,
                 minlength:8
               }
           },
        messages:
           {username:
              {
                required:"pls enter user name",
                minlength:"pls enter atleast {0} characters"
              },
            password:
              {
                required:"pls enter password",
                minlength:"password should be atleast {0} characters"
              }


           }
       });




  });

 </script> 
</head>  
 <body>


 <div data-role="page" id="login">
 <form name="login" id="formlogin" method="get" action="" accept-charset = "utf-8">

 <div style="background-image: url(css/lib/images/purty_wood.png); background-color:#D3BEAC; height:50%; margin-top:200px; border:6px groove orange;  width:100%; margin:0 auto;">

   <label for="username">USER NAME:</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" id= "usrname" placeholder="ali"  size="10" style="color:#ff9900;" required></input> </br>

   <label for = "password">PASSWORD:</label>
   <input type = "password" name="password" id="usrpswd" placeholder="please enter your password" style="color:#ff9900;" required title="User name is required"></input></br>

   <a href="#" id ="loginbtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" onclick="doLogin1();" style= "width:120px;" "height:60px;" "float:right;">LOGIN</a>
   <a href="#" id ="signupbtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" onclick="showRegisterForm();" style="width:120px;" "height:60px;" "float:right;">SIGN UP</a>

 </div>
</form>
 </div> 


<div data-role="page" id="registration">
 <form name="" id="formregistration"  method="get" action="">

  <div style="background-image:url('/helloworld/assets/www/css/lib/images/purty_wood.png'); height:30%; border:3px solid-black; position:absolute; top:25%; left:25%; right:25%; width:350px;">

  <label for="usernameforreg">USER NAME:</label>
  <input type="text" name="usernameforreg" id="usrnameforreg" placeholder="pls enter your name" style="color:#ff9900;" required></input></br>

  <label for="emailid">EMAIL ID:</label> 
  <input type="email" name="useremail" id="useremail" placeholder="please enter your email id" style="color:#ff9900;" required></input></br>

  <label for="passwordforreg">PASSWORD:</label>
  <input type="password" name="passwordforreg" id="passwordforreg" palceholder="pls enter your password" style="color:#ff9900;"></input></br>

  <label for="retypepassword">RETYPE PASSWORD:</label>
  <input type="password" name="retypepassword" id="retypepasswordforreg" palceholder="retype password" style="color:#ff9900;" classrequired></input></br>

  <a href="#" id="submitbtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" onclick="registrationProcess();" style="width:120px;" "height:60px;" "float:center;">SUBMIT</a>

  </div>
 </form> 

</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier for us, here at SO, if you could post your examples with all the extraneous & superfluous code stripped out.  We don't need to see all the inline styles, for example.

Anyhow, I found a bunch of issues...

---

1)  You are not including the scripts properly.  You want jQuery first (and once) and everything else after that.  Check your syntax very carefully; you were missing a closing `</script>` tag from `additional-methods.js`.  You also do not need to include both the minified and un-minified version of the same script... just pick one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jqm.page.params.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/helloworldjs/alldatabse.js"></script>
```

---

2)  In your forms, you have some invalid HTML.  Inputs and line breaks are "self-closing"...

**not** like this:    `<input></input>` and `</br>`

**yes, like this:**  `<input />` and `<br />`

---

3)  You are using inline JavaScript to call other functions using inline `onclick` event handlers.  Since you're using jQuery, you might as well take full advantage of it.  Remove the inline JavaScript and do something like this, which effectively turns your anchor tag into a submit button.

```
$('#loginbtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#formlogin").submit();
});
```

---

4)  Inside your form HTML, you can change `required` into `required="required"` which is better syntax.  BTW, since you already declared `required` within `.validate()`, you don't need to specify those rules again within the HTML... do one or the other... no need for both.  I removed these from the HTML.

---

5)  Since you're already specifying all messages within `.validate()`, I removed the `title` attribute from the inputs.

---

6)  You misspelled the `placeholder` attribute as `palceholder` in a couple of places.

---

With everything (I think) fixed, jQuery Validation appears to be working:

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/5T3tq/1/**

You can now slowly add back your other plugins and functionality

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#loginbtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#formlogin").submit();
    });

    $('#submitbtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#formregistration").submit();
    });

    $('#signupbtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //  show register form
        $('#registration').show();
    });

    $("#formregistration").validate({
        rules: {
            usernameforreg: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 10

            },
            useremail: {
                required: true,
                email: true

            },
            passwordforreg: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            retypepassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#passwordforreg"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            usernameforreg: {
                required: "pls enter name",
                minlength: $.format("Keep typing, at least {0} characters required!"),
                maxlength: $.format("Maximum {0} characters allowed!")

            },
            useremail: {
                required: "pls enter email id",
                email: "enter valid email id"
            },
            passwordforreg: {
                required: "pls enter password",
                minlength: $.format("at least {0} characters required!")
            },
            retypepassword: {
                required: "pls confirm password",
                equalTo: "both passwords must match"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#formlogin").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "pls enter user name",
                minlength: "pls enter atleast {0} characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "pls enter password",
                minlength: "password should be atleast {0} characters"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <form name="login" id="formlogin" method="get" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="background-image: url(css/lib/images/purty_wood.png); background-color:#D3BEAC; height:50%; margin-top:200px; border:6px groove orange;  width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
            <label for="username">USER NAME:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="usrname" placeholder="ali" size="10" style="color:#ff9900;" />
            <br />
            <label for="password">PASSWORD:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="usrpswd" placeholder="please enter your password" style="color:#ff9900;" />
            <br /> <a href="#" id="loginbtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" style="width:120px;" "height:60px;" "float:right;">LOGIN</a>
 <a href="#" id="signupbtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" style="width:120px;" "height:60px;" "float:right;">SIGN UP</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="registration" style="display: none;">
    <form name="" id="formregistration" method="get" action="">
        <div style="background-image:url('/helloworld/assets/www/css/lib/images/purty_wood.png'); height:30%; border:3px solid-black; position:absolute; top:25%; left:25%; right:25%; width:350px;">
            <label for="usernameforreg">USER NAME:</label>
            <input type="text" name="usernameforreg" id="usrnameforreg" placeholder="pls enter your name" style="color:#ff9900;" />
            <br />
            <label for="emailid">EMAIL ID:</label>
            <input type="email" name="useremail" id="useremail" placeholder="please enter your email id" style="color:#ff9900;" />
            <br />
            <label for="passwordforreg">PASSWORD:</label>
            <input type="password" name="passwordforreg" id="passwordforreg" placeholder="pls enter your password" style="color:#ff9900;" />
            <br />
            <label for="retypepassword">RETYPE PASSWORD:</label>
            <input type="password" name="retypepassword" id="retypepasswordforreg" placeholder="retype password" style="color:#ff9900;" />
            <br/> <a href="#" id="submitbtn" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" style="width:120px;" "height:60px;" "float:center;">SUBMIT</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your co-operation  i'll try my best to correct my code and will check the result and pls let me know which web sites or book  i can follow for phone-gap as i m new in this development and facing difficulty regarding jquery and JS

Comment: @ErumHannan, I don't know about any books, but I learned about jQuery at [the jQuery website](http://jquery.com/), reading about it here at SO, and by experimenting with my own code in jsFiddle.  It just takes time.